# Are rubber couplings allowed for drain stack in Ontario?

Tags: plumbing

I need to modify my drain stack somewhat. I want turn a T in the stack to the back wall to make space in the wall.

To do this, I need to cut the drain stack and, obviously, reconnect it after I turn the T. But since there is’t enough movement to put in a solid connector, I was looking into using the rubber Fernco connector. I’m having troubles determining if this meets code.
Here is a picture. I’ll be cutting the stack above and below the T to rotate it to the back. The intention is to use the Fernco rubber connectors to reattach the pipes. Eventually this will be behind a wall.

Ok, so my question is, in Ontario Canada, do you know if it meets code to put in the Fernco rubber connectors in a vertical drain stack.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why would you be able to install a no-hub coupling but not an ABS repair coupling?

Comment: @isherwood, I’ve updated the post to include a specific question. Also, in your comment regarding the ABS repair coupling, are you referring to the solid ABS coupling? If so, I can’t use the solid coupling as there is no movement of the stack in order insert the coupling. Or, does your reply suggest that the no-hub and ABS coupling can be interchanged freely, and as such, there is no issue with using the no-hub coupling?

Comment: I'm saying that you have to slip a no-hub coupling onto the pipe somehow (they don't have zippers), and therefore you should be able to slip on a repair coupling just as easily  (or more so, since they're shorter). No-hub couplings are mostly used to connect pipes of disparate material. They don't necessarily make the job easier.

Comment: Your photo doesn't show what's above the tee, where you'd have to cut the pipe. It might help if we could see that. Obviously you can't cut between the adjacent fittings we see there, so you'll have to go above. (Or was your plan to put a rubber coupling _over_ the two fitting flanges?)

Comment: If your question really is just about local code, we're not your huckleberry. If you want help with the actual fix, show and tell us more. :)

Comment: @isherwood  I have not used many ABS couplings but the few I did had a ridge inside to act as a stop.  Can you confirm that some do not and can slide fully up/down a pipe.  OP can probably use a solid piece for one joint, but the second would need something to slip on pipe fully before joining(if top and bottom sections can't move).

Comment: You're planning on turning the T to face the wall. I presume you have some sort of plan to also adjust the smaller pipe coming _out_ of the T as well? How are you going to replumb that?

Comment: Repair couplings do not have internal stops. Hence the name. :)

Comment: Thanks for the input and discussion @isherwood. I’ve added a picture to see what is above. Beyond the top of that, it goes through the second floor and presumably through the roof. I’ve also added a drawn picture (an artist I am not!) to show where that pipe goes from the T. (I assume this is for venting?). So my want, is to spin that T to make room for cupboards. To do this, I need to cut above and below the T (reroute that vent pipe) and reconnect where the two cuts were done. The key is that I’m not able to move that stack up or down. Not sure the way to reconnect

Comment: Sounds good, but your question currently only asks about code, and not about your plans. You'll want to move all that information up there so we can answer what's actually in the question.

Answer (score 2):

To learn whether a no-hub coupler is allowed, call your local inspection office. A quick description of the project should make the application fairly clear and you'll have your answer.

It may be a moot question, though. I'd be doing something like this:

1. Cut below the tee and above the existing coupler above the tee and the reducer. Also cut off the small pipe that comes off the tee below *its* coupler. It's wise to eliminate joints you don't need for reliability, etc.
2. Slide a repair coupling onto the small upper stub.
3. Rebuild your intersection as you like, fitting the mate to the upper stub closely to it. You may be able to flex the upper stub aside to get the rest together. If not, see below.
4. Mark equal distances above and below the stub joint so you can visually center the repair coupling.
5. Apply cement and spin the repair coupling down into place with at least a full turn once on the cement.

Dry-fit everything first. If you find that you really can't flex the  upper stub to the side enough to make this plan work, put *two* repair couplings in that run, with a short pipe between. The last step will be to drop in that short pipe and cement the repair couplings.

Look, Ma! No rubber parts!